# Retrieve letter position on hover

Tags: javascript, string

Every letter doesn't have it's own wrapper element, everything is inside paragraph.

And I am wondering if I can retrieve the position of the letter in string when I hover over it's parent element?

For example: `<p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</p>` has `innerText.length = 43`, if I hover over `f`, it should return `16`.

Any way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: get the mouse position and the x/y offset of the <p> and do some math. with a common font and fixed size it might work.

Comment: With a fixed font - yes. Probably should've mentioned that no fixed font will be used and there will be varying sizes for the letters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Options for you:

1. To use Canvas (HTML5) and in particular its
   `context.measureText(text).width`. But this will give 
   you position in single line text.
2. To use cursor/range in contenteditable, see
   [Get caret (cursor) position in contentEditable area containing HTML content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767848/get-caret-cursor-position-in-contenteditable-area-containing-html-content) for example.

Comment: Canvas won't cut it this time, too expensive for what am I building. About caret.. is there a way to apply it on hover?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to put every letter into its own `<span />`.  http://letteringjs.com/ might be useful to you, depending on what you're trying to do.

Comment: Currently working on this without lettering tho'. But it gets pretty interesting for nested elements, hehe.