# How to get cursor position from multiline RichTextArea in GWT?

Tags: javascript, gwt

I've already read the former article ["How to get cursor position or location from RichTextArea in GWT"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12542522/how-to-get-cursor-position-or-location-from-richtextarea-in-gwt). And the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12544613/1606556) work so far. After my implementation I was able to track the cursorposition as long as I wrote a single line.

I have no clue how to alter the solution to track the cursor position over more than one line.

**Error-example:**

```
"My name is Tharmar.|"   Position = 19(19) => correct
"My name is Tharmar.
 and I hope someone can help me|" Position = 30(49) => incorrect 

(int) = correct position
|=cursor
```

I would like to alter the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12544613/1606556) to get the "absolute" position of the curser within the RichTextArea. Is there a possibility to aggregate the positions (19+30)?

Can someone help me or point me in the right direction?

FYI: I have no experience with JavaScript!

Comment: Hi , u got any solution for that , I am stuck in the same problem for last 2 days, If you can please share your solution. thanks

Comment: Hey junaidp, sry but I didn't solve that one. I did a workaround by using another widget. I guess it was textarea. good look 4 u ! and if you solve it the topic will welcome you again ;)