# How to get the cursor position in contentEditable containing HTML?

Tags: javascript, contenteditable, cursor-position

I need to get the cursor position in a contentEditable div. I get some helpful function from [Get a range's start and end offset's relative to its parent container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811822/get-a-ranges-start-and-end-offsets-relative-to-its-parent-container/4812022#4812022) and https://stackoverflow.com/a/4770562/2008261.

But these function do NOT help because I need the actual position in the HTML, Here is what I need.

if I have:

```
<div id="diva" contenteditable="true">Insert <b>text here</b></div>
```

and I put the cursor just before the word "text" it returns 7 as it deals with the text. But I need it to return 10 as if it deals with the inner HTML of the contentEditabe div.

These are the function I mentioned before :

```
function getCaretCharacterOffsetWithin(element) {
var caretOffset = 0;
if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
    var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    var preCaretRange = range.cloneRange();
    preCaretRange.selectNodeContents(element);
    preCaretRange.setEnd(range.endContainer, range.endOffset);
    caretOffset = preCaretRange.toString().length;
} else if (typeof document.selection != "undefined" && document.selection.type != "Control") {
    var textRange = document.selection.createRange();
    var preCaretTextRange = document.body.createTextRange();
    preCaretTextRange.moveToElementText(element);
    preCaretTextRange.setEndPoint("EndToEnd", textRange);
    caretOffset = preCaretTextRange.text.length;
}
return caretOffset;
}
```

And :

```
function getCharacterOffsetWithin(range, node) {
var treeWalker = document.createTreeWalker(
    node,
    NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,
    function(node) {
        var nodeRange = document.createRange();
        nodeRange.selectNode(node);
        return nodeRange.compareBoundaryPoints(Range.END_TO_END, range) < 1 ?
            NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT : NodeFilter.FILTER_REJECT;
    },
    false
);

var charCount = 0;
while (treeWalker.nextNode()) {
    charCount += treeWalker.currentNode.length;
}
if (range.startContainer.nodeType == 3) {
    charCount += range.startOffset;
}
return charCount;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to use a cross-browser library like [rangy](https://code.google.com/p/rangy/)?

Comment: @VladMagdalin , rangy is awesome. It had more than what I needed

Answer (score 0):

Having had to tackle this before ( I created an web based word processor ): the only viable solution is to walk up the DOM tree and count both innerHTML and outerHTML lengths, and then use the offset within the range if there is one.

I also highly discourage the use of contentEditable implementations, you'll spend far more time trying to fix what is wrong with them and trying to override their behaviors than you will coding the features you actually want.

My implementation was a function that took a range offset and walked up until it hit the specified boundary parent.  Some things to keep in mind, previous siblings are easy to add, but wrapping parents are tricky with attributes etc. to account for in length.

My calculation was to take the whole length of a node `"<div id="" class="" foo="bar">sometext</div>"`, subtract the length of the `innerHTML`, subtract the length of the `tagname`, and `subtract 3` to get the length of `<div id="" class="" foo="bar">`

BUT unless YOU controlled the creation of that HTML, your count could still be wrong, as depending on browser multiple spaces in a row are returned as either 1 char or multiple chars when testing length.

Comment: if I don't use contentEditable implementations, what shall I use instead. I can't implement textarea to do my needs. I agree with you that it has many many problems and very confusing as I code very much codes but what is the other solution to it?

Comment: Why can't you implement a textarea? The hidden textarea is a far more useful trick than iframes or content editables.

Comment: actually I'm using both of them, a textarea and contentEditable. The contentEditable is what the user interacts with and the textarea is hidden. When the user write something or style something in the contentEditable it reflects in the hidden textarea. So the textarea keeps the html markups then a jQuery code makes a bridge between both of them. But I can't use the textarea alone because it doesn't support displaying text in HTML format. I think your word processor implements the same concept. Isn't it?

Comment: no it does not, mine actively edits the actual html using javascript by using the textarea to capture key and paste events.

Comment: For your implementation, if you're walking the DOM, why would you need to look at `innerHTML` and `outerHTML`? Since there are many potential valid HTML representations of the DOM tree a browser could produce, an offset within one of them is meaningless.

Comment: I also partially disagree with you about avoiding contenteditable: it really depends on your requirements. For a simple editor, it could well be fine. That said, I do use a variation on the hidden textarea approach in my current project.

Comment: You have to look at both because doing traditional OT you need a character offset independent of whether those characters are visible or not.  And yes, for some basic situations a contentEditable is fine, but I've also been able to build far better apps by avoiding it.