# Get caret index in contenteditable div including tags

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable, getcaretpos

I have a `contentEditable` *div* in which I have multiple tags (`br`, `b`, `u`, `i`) and text.

I need to get the caret index position relative to the div, including all the tags.

#### For example:

```
<div id="h" contenteditable="true">abc<b>def<br>ghi</b>jkl</div>
```

If the cursor is between `g` and `h`, I need the caret index position to be `14`.
The problem is that the found methods that use a [`treeWalker`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TreeWalker) do not work in this case.
The bold tag is not found... probably because it isn't closed.
Also I have tried several methods but still no luck.

I need it to work in *Firefox*.
Thank you.

Comment: Why do you need this number? It's essentially meaningless since there many ways to represent the same DOM with different HTML which will affect the number (e.g. by using `<br />` in stead of `<br>`). I'm assuming you want this so you can get an offset relative to the HTML string you're sending from the server to the browser.

Comment: yes... that's exactly why I need the number. I have tried several means but still no success.

Comment: There is no way of getting back the original HTML string via the DOM, so you'll need to re-request the page via Ajax, parse the HTML and match it up to the current DOM. It's going to be quite tricky.

Answer (score 23):

Have you tried this?
[Get a range's start and end offset's relative to its parent container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811822/get-a-ranges-start-and-end-offsets-relative-to-its-parent-container/4812022#4812022)

Direct link to the jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/TjXEG/1/

Function code:

```
function getCaretCharacterOffsetWithin(element) {
    var caretOffset = 0;
    if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
        var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
        var preCaretRange = range.cloneRange();
        preCaretRange.selectNodeContents(element);
        preCaretRange.setEnd(range.endContainer, range.endOffset);
        caretOffset = preCaretRange.toString().length;
    } else if (typeof document.selection != "undefined" && document.selection.type != "Control") {
        var textRange = document.selection.createRange();
        var preCaretTextRange = document.body.createTextRange();
        preCaretTextRange.moveToElementText(element);
        preCaretTextRange.setEndPoint("EndToEnd", textRange);
        caretOffset = preCaretTextRange.text.length;
    }
    return caretOffset;
}

function showCaretPos() {
    var el = document.getElementById("test");
    var caretPosEl = document.getElementById("caretPos");
    caretPosEl.innerHTML = "Caret position: " + getCaretCharacterOffsetWithin(el);
}

document.body.onkeyup = showCaretPos;
document.body.onmouseup = showCaretPos;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem is that the <br> is not taken into consideration when determining the caret position.

Comment: @helldrain I wonder if you managed to find a solution that includes the tags.

Comment: is there any function that includes length of the tags as well . ?

Answer (score 10):

just had to do this so there is some working solution (some testing may be required)

basic idea is to:

1. get textContent position using this method: [Get caret (cursor) position in contentEditable area containing HTML content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767848/get-caret-cursor-position-in-contenteditable-area-containing-html-content)
2. iterate through innerHTML of an element to the textContent position
3. if html tag or entity is encountered, iterate through it until normal char, then continue

sample code here:

```
function getCaretPosition (node) {
    var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0),
        preCaretRange = range.cloneRange(),
        caretPosition,
        tmp = document.createElement("div");

    preCaretRange.selectNodeContents(node);
    preCaretRange.setEnd(range.endContainer, range.endOffset);
    tmp.appendChild(preCaretRange.cloneContents());
    caretPosition = tmp.innerHTML.length;
    return caretPosition;
}

function getHTMLCaretPosition(element) {
var textPosition = getCaretPosition(element),
    htmlContent = element.innerHTML,
    textIndex = 0,
    htmlIndex = 0,
    insideHtml = false,
    htmlBeginChars = ['&', '<'],
    htmlEndChars = [';', '>'];


if (textPosition == 0) {
  return 0;
}

while(textIndex < textPosition) {

  htmlIndex++;

  // check if next character is html and if it is, iterate with htmlIndex to the next non-html character
  while(htmlBeginChars.indexOf(htmlContent.charAt(htmlIndex)) > -1) {
    // console.log('encountered HTML');
    // now iterate to the ending char
    insideHtml = true;

    while(insideHtml) {
      if (htmlEndChars.indexOf(htmlContent.charAt(htmlIndex)) > -1) {
        if (htmlContent.charAt(htmlIndex) == ';') {
          htmlIndex--; // entity is char itself
        }
        // console.log('encountered end of HTML');
        insideHtml = false;
      }
      htmlIndex++;
    }
  }
  textIndex++;
}

//console.log(htmlIndex);
//console.log(textPosition);
// in htmlIndex is caret position inside html
return htmlIndex;
}
```

Comment: You are my hero. This worked beautifully and saved me hours of tears.

Comment: What function is being referenced for `getCaretPosition(element)`? It doesn't appear you've included its definition.

Comment: @CFitz read first point of the answer, there is link for that function

Comment: How to get selected text?

Comment: it works! life saving @YangombiUmpakati thanks man