# How to append text in contenteditable div with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a contenteditable div:

```
<div contenteditable="true"  title="sometitle"  id="ftext"></div>
```

and jQuery code:

```
$('#htmadd').click(function(){
    $('#ftext').append($('#htmtext').val());
});
```

How can I append code from #htmtext to #ftext with converting in html tags and on cursor position.
(or just how to get cursor position in this div)

Comment: "with converting in html tags" - what does that mean? Keeping the literal `<b>` in the text? Or making the text bold?

Comment: making the text bold

Comment: This might be useful [get-caret-position-in-contenteditable-div-including-tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16736680/get-caret-position-in-contenteditable-div-including-tags)

Comment: It should already be bold, check out this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nyho8mmp/)

Comment: yes, like this but append in cursor position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not really sure what you are asking, or is this two questions: 1) how do I get the contents on the `$('#htmtext')` to `$('#ftext')` ?

```
//get the html contents of an element
var stuff = $('#htmtext').html();
//add the html to an element
$('#ftext').append(stuff)
```

as for getting the cursor position, that has been [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811822/get-a-ranges-start-and-end-offsets-relative-to-its-parent-container/4812022#4812022):