# Get the child node index of an element having the caret position to its contenteditable parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery, parent-child, contenteditable, caret

Now I have asked this question before and it was marked as duplicate to this question [Get caret position in contenteditable div including tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16736680/get-caret-position-in-contenteditable-div-including-tags) But infact it is totally different.

Lets say I have a contenteditable div which also has some element in it

```
<div id="text" contenteditable="true"><b>abc</b><nav>def</nav><span>ghi</span></div>
```

Now if the cursor or caret position is within the `span` element, how do I get the index of the `span` element as a child node to its parent element `div`. So I can have this result

```
divNode = document.querySelector('div');
caretEle = //get the caret position element which will be span
spanIndex = //probably divNode.indexOf(caretEle) which will be = 2
caretEle = divNode.childNodes[spanIndex];
```

**NOTE:** I am not looking for the caret position, I want to get the child index of the caret position element to its parent element. ie I want to get the child index of the `<span>` element to the `<div id="text" contenteditable="true">`

For example:

```
node = document.getElementById('text');
node.childNodes[0] == <b>
node.childNodes[1] == <nav>
node.childNodes[2] == <span>
```

Comment: there's no simple way, but you can do something like `[].indexOf.call(node.parentNode.children, node)` on each parent, probably inside one of those `while( node=node.parentNode)` kind of loops

Comment: Do you even know that the caret-span is a child of the div? Could it be in a <p> that is a child of the div?

Comment: @Alan yes it is a child of the div not in a `<p>` element

Comment: Okay, then basically like @dandavis said will work. Or walk through previousSibling until you hit null.

Comment: Have you a working solution for this question?

Comment: Do you have any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

```
var s = window.getSelection();
var an = s.anchorNode;
var fn = s.focusNode;
```

The `anchorNode` represents the `textNode` where selection *begins* while the `focusNode` is where the selection *ends*; presuming that the elements contain a textNode otherwise the browser *might* return the element itself. It's *very* important to remember that the `anchorNode` is where the user initially *started* the selection, so if they selected from right-to-left, the `anchorNode` will be on the right side whereas if they selected the text from left-to-right the `anchorNode` will be on the *left* side.