# AngularJS contenteditble div - need to get caret position

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've this directive extracted from http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/common-user-interface-patterns/editing-text-in-place-using-html5-content-editable.html that's works very good.

here is my code.

```
angular
.module('app')
.directive("formulaEditor", function() {
return {
    restrict: "A",
    require: "ngModel",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        function read() {
            ngModel.$setViewValue(element.html());
        }
        ngModel.$render = function() {
            element.html(ngModel.$viewValue || "");
        };
        element.bind("blur keyup change", function() {
            scope.$apply(read);
        });
    }
};
});

<div formula-editor id="editor" contenteditable="true" ng-model="kpiForm.formula"></div>
```

I need to get the cursor position on my div. I don't know how to implement this code that I found (not using angular) : [Get caret position in contenteditable div including tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16736680/get-caret-position-in-contenteditable-div-including-tags)

Can someone help with this ? ty !

Comment: Hi, I am looking for something similar. Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score -1):

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.directive("formulaEditor", function() {
return {
    restrict: "A",
    require: "ngModel",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        function read() {
            ngModel.$setViewValue(element.html());
        }
        ngModel.$render = function() {
           debugger;
            document.getElementById('editor').focus();
            element.html(ngModel.$viewValue || "");
        };
        element.bind("blur keyup change", function() {
            scope.$apply(read);
        });
    }
};
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">

<div formula-editor id="editor" contenteditable="true" ng-model="kpiForm.formula" style="border:2px solid black;"  tabindex="-1"></div>

</body>
```

Hi, I had updated the code to focus cursor on the "div". will this helpful to you?

Comment: I appreciate , @praveen, but I'm trying to figure out a way to get the caret position. If the cursor is actually on the 5th character, for example...

Comment: @MarcoJr U mean window.getSelection() in which where u can find the focusOffset value which gives the caret position of the cursor.