# Capture the last entered word, from middle of the text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to capture the last word the user typed in the div/textarea. 
It's not a problem when the word is the last word. But what if user entered the word inside (in the middle) of the paragraph?

For now I have this code:

```
<div contenteditable="true">Add text here</div>
<script>
    $("div").on("keyup", function(e){
      if (e.keyCode === 0 || e.keyCode === 32) {
        var words = $(this).text().trim().split(' '),
            lastWord = words[words.length - 1];
        console.log(lastWord);
        }
    });
</script>
```

It takes the last word of the text after user hit space.

Comment: Works as expected, what's the issue?

Comment: You're probably going to have to store the original contents and do some form of a diff with the new contents.

Comment: @Mr.Alien he doesn't want the last word in the div. He wants the last word added by the user regardless of where it was added.

Comment: @mkaatman Aaah I see, I've a solution to that

Comment: @Mr.Alien could you share it? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the substring of the text up to the cursor position, which you can get with the `window.getSelection` function:

```js
$('div').on('keyup', function (ev) {
  if (ev.keyCode <= 32) { // Can be extended to all non-alphanumeric.
    var el = ev.target;
    var selection = getSelection();
    var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
    var line = range.endContainer.nodeValue || '';
    var cursor = selection.focusOffset;
    if (!line) {
      var childNodes = selection.anchorNode.parentNode.childNodes;
      for (var i = 0; i < childNodes.length; i++) {
        if (childNodes[i] == selection.anchorNode) {break;}
        if (childNodes[i].outerHTML) {
          if (childNodes[i].innerText) {line += ' ' + childNodes[i].innerText.trim();}
        } else if (childNodes[i].nodeType == 3) {
          if (childNodes[i].textContent) {line += ' ' + childNodes[i].textContent.trim();}
        }
      }
      line = line.trim();
      cursor = line.length;
    }
    var words = line.replace(/\W+/gm, ' ').substring(0, cursor).trim().split(' ');
    var lastWord = words[words.length - 1];
    console.log(lastWord);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div contenteditable="true" style="min-height: 80px;">
  Add text here<br/>
  Or do it in this line<br/>
  newline
</div>
```

Comment: If user malfunctions the input i.e. I hit the spaces multiple times before and after each word so this doesn't work on that space event. probably we need to capture each keystroke.

Comment: Thanks. But there is a problem if user used Enter. Try to hit  enter and continue to write..

Comment: I extended the solution for multiline texts. Hope it helps.

Comment: Updated solution to get the last word before Enter.

Answer (score 1):

Store each word in array on keypress event so you can capture the order of words typed by the user. Take last word after splitting with space.

For e.g. If user has typed:

"This is the test information" then he types "updated" word before "information" word so the statement is like "This is test updated information":

So in above array, sequence of words would be:

"This is the test information updated", we can then split array and after splitting, we will get "updated" as the last word which we want.

Comment: That is assuming the user moves the caret to the beginning of the word 'information' and types 'updated', hits <space>. I tend to click the end of the previous word, add another space and type the word. Not an easy problem.

Probably need to track keystrokes, add click handlers, arrow key handlers... ugh, this is an awful problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the caret position, and from it, return back to recover the whole word. You can test it here:

```
$("div").on("keyup", function(e){
  if (e.keyCode === 13 || e.keyCode === 32) {
    var text = $(this).text();            
    var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    var preCaretRange = range.cloneRange();
    preCaretRange.selectNodeContents(e.target);
    preCaretRange.setEnd(range.endContainer, range.endOffset);
    caretOffset = preCaretRange.toString().length;

    var word = "";
    var iterator = caretOffset-1;
    var blanks = String.fromCharCode(160) + " \n"; 
    // Skip blanks from right to left
    while (iterator >= 0 && blanks.indexOf(text[iterator]) > -1) {
        iterator--;
    }

    while (iterator >= 0 && blanks.indexOf(text[iterator]) == -1) {
    console.log(text[iterator].charCodeAt(0));
        word = text[iterator] + word;
      iterator -= 1;
    }
    console.log(word.trim());
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7Lgpvgwc/1/

I've got the caret position from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16736680/get-caret-position-in-contenteditable-div-including-tags#16737647).

**Edit**: It looks like contentEditable newline uses nbsp (non-breaking spaces) instead of newlines.

Comment: Its edited now. Content-editable div newlines are non-breaking spaces, something that I never noticed.