# Indenting in contenteditable div without using .execCommand()

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create jQuery that will indent a div when the `tab` key is pressed. I found this code, which works fine:

```
$('[contenteditable]').on('keydown', function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 9){
        e.preventDefault();
        document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, '&#009');
    }
});
```

However, when looking at the API documentation (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand), it states:

```
Obsolete
This feature is obsolete. Although it may still work in some browsers, its use is discouraged since it could be removed at any time. Try to avoid using it.
```

Are there any alternatives to using `.execCommand()`?

Comment: This is surprisingly complicated. You first need to check whether the user has highlighted something (`window.getSelection()`) or just has his cursor somewhere in your div, and if the latter, then where. You may check out questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811822/get-a-ranges-start-and-end-offsets-relative-to-its-parent-container) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16736680/get-caret-index-in-contenteditable-div-including-tags) on that topic. Then you can do the easy part, replacing/inserting the content with something like `insertAdjacentHTML`.