# How to find the length of characters before and after the caret in contenteditable div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to javascript. I have to find length of characters before and after the caret position in contenteditable div.

Is it possible.

please Help me.......

Comment: Please share some HTML

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767848/get-caret-cursor-position-in-contenteditable-area-containing-html-content

Answer (score 0):

Using JavaScript and jQuery:

```
var string = $(".contenteditable").contents().text();
var result = string.split("^");
var preceedingLength = result[0].length;
var proceedingLength = result[1].length;
alert(preceedingLength);
alert(proceedingLength);
```

This assumes that you have only one caret in your `DIV`.

Comment: I think the OP means the editing caret rather than a caret character.

Comment: Oh! Well, at least I learnt to wait for more context the next time!