# weird beheviour after removing an element from contentEditable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, contenteditable

I have some `<div>`'s with `class=tgg` inside the `contentEditable <div>` .

the `<div>`'s with `class=tgg` are also `contentEditable` (it is required).

The problem occurs when user removes that particular `.tgg` div's content. It seems like that div is removed; But after starting typing a span is created in chrome with same style as that of `.tgg` and wraps the typed text in it. which produces undesirable effects that should be avoided.

Here is My code:

HTML:

```
<div id="tarea" contentEditable="true" class="tarea" autocorrect="false" spellCheck="off">
<div class="tgg">Vedant Terkar</div> 
Creates another <div class="tgg">Fiddle</div> 
for all <div class='tgg'>SO</div> Users.

</div>

<textarea id="opc" rows="5" cols="97">
</textarea>
```

CSS:

```
.tarea{
    width:99%;
    height:300px;
    overflow:auto;
    clear:both;
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px solid #000;
    padding:5px;
    outline:none;
    color:#333;
    }
    .tarea .tgg{
    background:#99d;
    color:#fff;
    padding:1px;
    border:1px solid #77b; 
    display:inline-block;
    }
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#tarea").keyup(function(e){
    var html=$(this).html().toString().trim();
    html=html.split("<br>").join("\n");
    html=html.split("&nbsp;").join(" ");
        $("#opc").val(html);
        $(this).find(".tgg").each(function(){
        $(this).attr("contenteditable","true");
        });
    });
    $("#tarea").trigger("keyup");
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Vedant_Terkar/Y8F7X/)

---

Here is what I'm trying to say:

Here is output of the code as you can see:
[image: Orginal OP]

When you put your cursor(caret) between `fiddle` and `for` and remove the `fiddle` using <kbd>BackSpace</kbd> or <kbd>Del</kbd> It is removed as follows:

[image: working]

But now if you start typing any thing it'll not be produced as plain text but it'll be inside a `<span>` like:

[image: Problem]

I'm using `chrome`. output may vary for different `browser`. Can anyone tell me how can i fix this problem?
any suggestion is welcome. Thanks in advance :)!

Comment: It's up to the browser how it generates the elements. You fix one thing in one browser and it causes another unwanted behavior in other browsers.

Comment: @undefined, thats true. Is there anyway to make it work uniformly for all browsers? if not can you please help me fixing this in chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#tarea").on("keyup", function(e){
    var html=$(this).html().toString().trim();
    html=html.split("<br>").join("\n");
    html=html.split("&nbsp;").join(" ");
        $("#opc").val(html);
        $(this).find(".tgg").each(function(){
        $(this).attr("contenteditable","true");
        });
        // replace `font` with `text` within `font`
        // TODO: change caret (cursor) position ,
        // following `replaceWith()` call ,
        // to position _after_ replaced element
        $("font").each(function(i, el) {
          $(el).replaceWith($(el).text());
        });        
    }).trigger("keyup");
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/h7h97/

See

[How to move cursor to end of contenteditable entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125292/how-to-move-cursor-to-end-of-contenteditable-entity)

[Set cursor position on contentEditable <div>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181700/set-cursor-position-on-contenteditable-div)

[Get caret (cursor) position in contentEditable area containing HTML content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767848/get-caret-cursor-position-in-contenteditable-area-containing-html-content)

Comment: Thanks a lot mate :). this fixed that problem. But Can you please also make it work in FireFox? this isn't working there. +1 for efforts.

Comment: That fixed it :)! Thanks. But can you please explain how can I make cursor work properly after `.replaceWith()` does its work?

Comment: @VedantTerkar See links at post , `TODO`. Perhaps a useful and distinct Question in and of itself ?