# Insert smiley at cursor position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making a project where users can click on the smileys and they get inserted in contenteditable div.

1. I want three divs and in whatever div I am, the smiley should insert in that div.
2. Also, here the problem is that smileys only insert at the end of the div. I want that smiley should enter only wherever is the cursor.

*Note: please check that the size of smileys should remain same in all the divs.*

```
<div id="text_wrapper">
    <div id="text" contentEditable="true" hidefocus="true"></div>
</div>
<div id="text_wrapper">
   <div id="text1" contentEditable="true" hidefocus="true"></div>
</div>
<div id="text_wrapper">
   <div id="text2" contentEditable="true" hidefocus="true"></div>
</div>
<span id="button">Add Emoji</span>
```

---

```
$("#button").click(function() {
  $("#text").append('<img src="https://cdn.okccdn.com/media/img/emojis/apple/1F60C.png"/>');
});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/x6ud5wxt/1/)

Comment: Your question is not clear.. Kindly elaborate.

Comment: To get the cursor position within a contentEditable element you can take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767848/get-caret-cursor-position-in-contenteditable-area-containing-html-content

Comment: Use focusin event to set the current div (See https://jsfiddle.net/x6ud5wxt/3/). Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181700/set-cursor-position-on-contenteditable-div for how to control the cursor position after adding the smiley..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First: insert into the right one of the three elements:**

You are using the expression `#text` which refers to the first editable div.

If You'd like to target the one with the last focus on it, You can use classes for this.

Add a class to them, so You can easily target any of them

```
<div id="text_wrapper">

    <div id="text" class="editable" contentEditable="true" hidefocus="true"></div>

</div>

<div id="text_wrapper">

   <div id="text1" class="editable" contentEditable="true" hidefocus="true"></div>

</div>

<div id="text_wrapper">

   <div id="text2" class="editable" contentEditable="true" hidefocus="true"></div>

</div>

<span id="button">Add Emoji</span>
```

Then You can easily decide where the focus is with a single event listener

```
$( document ).on( "click focusin" , ".editable" , function(){

    $( ".editable" ).removeClass( "focus" );
    $( this ).addClass( "focus" );

} );
```

From this point, the focused item ( the one with the cursor ) will have the class ".focus".

Now, You can use

```
$( document ).on( "click" , "#button" , function() {

  $( ".editable.focus" ).append( '<img src="https://cdn.okccdn.com/media/img/emojis/apple/1F60C.png"/>' );

});
```

---

**Second: insert at the position of the cursor**

This seems to be a bit more complex, but there are pretty clean ways. Take a look at [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6690752/insert-html-at-caret-in-a-contenteditable-div).

Comment: I have just made the fiddle with your solution.. https://jsfiddle.net/x6ud5wxt/4/

Comment: Thanks @steven. But I am not getting how to get the cursor position. Also, if I had multiple smileys , how will i manage them. could you plz give me an idea

Comment: I tried your code. I want to know when I insert smiley in the first div, the smiley is small, but in the other divs, it gets bigger. @steven palinkas

Comment: Your declaration in the CSS: `#text img { width: 50px; }` can be corrected to target all the editable divs `.editable img { width: 50px; }`