# Insert emoji at cursor

Tags: jquery, html, css

I already asked this question earlier on stack overflow but didnot get a answer. I have 2 links called add emoji 1 and add emoji 2.
This was my ealier question.
[Insert smiley at cursor position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31513449/insert-smiley-at-cursor-position)

Now, even when I had made certain changes and the here the problem is that smileys only insert at the end of the div and not at the cursor position. 
My new demo is at: https://jsfiddle.net/ftwbx88p/8/

```
$( document ).on( "click" , "#button" , function() {
   $( ".editable.focus" ).append( '<img src="https://cdn.okccdn.com/media/img/emojis/apple/1F60C.png"/>' );
});
```

I want the smiley to insert in the respective contenteditable div where ever the cursor is. Thanks in advance.

**`Note: I had a contenteditable div where I want to add image and not in the textarea.`**

Answer (score 1):

I have tested this code for textbox with id txtUserName.Its working as you want

**Code:**

```
$(document).on("click", "#button1", function () {
        var cursorPosition = $("#txtUserName")[0].selectionStart;
        var FirstPart = $("#txtUserName").val().substring(0, cursorPosition);
        var NewText = " New text ";
        var SecondPart = $("#txtUserName").val().substring(cursorPosition + 1, $("#txtUserName").val().length);
        $("#txtUserName").val(FirstPart+NewText+SecondPart);
    });
```

Comment: Its not working @Muhammad Atif in my code. and I don't want to use form elements. I am using div.

Answer (score 0):

Please find below lines of code which will resolve your query.

```
function insertAtCursor(myField, myValue) {
    //IE support
    if (document.selection) {
        myField.focus();
        sel = document.selection.createRange();
        sel.text = myValue;
    }
    //MOZILLA and others
    else if (myField.selectionStart || myField.selectionStart == '0') {
        var startPos = myField.selectionStart;
        var endPos = myField.selectionEnd;
        myField.value = myField.value.substring(0, startPos)
            + myValue
            + myField.value.substring(endPos, myField.value.length);
    } else {
        myField.value += myValue;
    }
}
```

And it is a possible duplicate of [Insert text into textarea at cursor position (Javascript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11076975/insert-text-into-textarea-at-cursor-position-javascript)

**Please review the above link for the details**

Comment: From where to find myField, myValue - the parameters of the function @Amit Chhangani

Comment: or what is sel? this answer is lacking fullness

Comment: myField is the "div" in which you have to insert the emoji, and myValue is the link of the emoji to insert. And for details please follow the link. It will work in the same manner as it works with textarea.

Comment: Does this code works for contenteditable div @Amit Chhangani . I had tried it and its not working. and also I want to add image , not text