# Insert smiley in a contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I had already tried:

[Insert smiley at cursor position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31513449/insert-smiley-at-cursor-position)

[Insert emoji at cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31669198/insert-emoji-at-cursor)

I had asked these questions earlier on the stack overflow. But the answers that I got did not fit with my requirements.I want to insert smiley at the cursor position and in a contenteditable div. My Demo is on [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ftwbx88p/8/) .
Smileys only insert at the end of the div and not at the cursor position. Also, I want to insert the smiley in whatever div I click. This functionality is already working but the smiley always get added at the end of the div. Plz help me this as I had already tried a lot of methods.

```
 $( document ).on( "click" , "#button" , function() {
     $( ".editable.focus" ).append( '<img src="https://cdn.okccdn.com/media/img/emojis/apple/1F60C.png"/>' );
 });
```

> Note: I had a contenteditable div where I want to add image and not in the textarea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may help.

```
function insertTextAtCursor(text) { 
    var sel, range, html; 
    sel = window.getSelection();
    range = sel.getRangeAt(0); 
    range.deleteContents(); 
    var textNode = document.CreateElement("<img src="https://cdn.okccdn.com/media/img/emojis/apple/1F60C.png"/>");
    range.insertNode(textNode);
    range.setStartAfter(textNode);
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);        
}
```

Comment: can u add this in the fiddle and make it working. I am just a beginner in jquery @prashant patil

Comment: So, I guess there is no answer to this question @prashant patil

Comment: @Amanjot Kaur- i did some changes in you implementation u need to use buttons instead of span.... the updated demo is here https://jsfiddle.net/ftwbx88p/22/  ..... please vote up if atleast this helps you

Comment: The smiley is again inserting at the end

Comment: But why is the image is not showing @prashant patil

Comment: well thats the thing i am also worried about...... but yeah good news is that it is getting inserted at the cursor position as u wanted

Comment: yeah Thanks But I want to insert 20-30 images. so, do I have to write this code that number of times

Comment: Ok, it was the html syntax error. I got it working . https://jsfiddle.net/ftwbx88p/23/

Comment: well you can use this single code with dynamically changing the link,  i have hardcoded the link in the  $(textNode).prop("src","src='https://cdn.okccdn.com/media/img/emojis/apple/1F60C.png'/>'") instead of this u can us something like  $(textNode).prop("src",VariableWhichYouCanAssignTheImageSource) and make the lines oof code which i specified as a different function and just pass the image sources to that function and use them in your jquery ........

Comment: can u do this plz in the fiddle. I am just a beginner. So, dont know much about jquery. i had updated the fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/ftwbx88p/24/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84527/discussion-between-prashant-patil-and-amanjot-kaur).

Comment: jsfiddle.net/ftwbx88p/25   :- Updated