# Find the currently focused span element inside an editable div

Tags: javascript, html

I have a sample at [Finding currently focused span in an editable div](http://jsfiddle.net/3a6r8ux0/).

The editable div i.e. a div having the attribute `contenteditable="true"`, contains 3 different spans with each span wrapped in a div. A user could position the cursor in any one of the three spans. My goal is to find out which span is being edited when user clicks on a span content to start editing or types into it. I would like this to work on desktop or mobile devices.

I tried getting the span using `document.activeElement` as you can see in my code sample, but it gets the editable div and not the current span. I was looking for a JavaScript solution to this problem.

**Question:**
How would I get the id of span element whose text is being edited using JavaScript?

Html code

```
<div id="input" contenteditable="true" onfocus="findCurrentSpan(this)">
  <div>
    <span id="first">first span</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span id="second">second span</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span id="third">third span</span>
  </div>
</div>
<p id="info" style="color:green">

</p>
```

Javascript code

```
function findCurrentSpan(editor) {
var element = document.getElementById("input");
var currentSpan = document.activeElement;
document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = "Active element's id is " + currentSpan.id;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is, that you are going to select the active element from the whole Page, that's why it is called document.activElement.

Have a look a this SO Question [Get and set cursor position with contenteditable div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34091730/get-and-set-cursor-position-with-contenteditable-div)

Answer (score 0):

In your example `findCurrentSpan(this)` `this` is referring to the function `findCurrentSpan()` so `this.id` will have the value input.

```
 <div id="input" contenteditable="true" onfocus="findCurrentSpan(this)">
```

To solve your problem, I recommend you bind an onfocus event to all of `input`'s children ([explanation on how the onfocus event works in javascript](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onfocus.asp)).

This is how you select all the span elements inside `input`:

```
var children = document.getElementById("input").querySelectorAll('span');
```

After selecting the elements you want to bind an event to. Use a loop to bind an event to all the elements. As far as I know `span` doesn't implement a `focus` state so we will have to use `click`.

```
children.forEach(function(e) {
    document.getElementById(e.id).addEventListener("click", findCurrentSpan)
})
```

The code will look like this:

```
function findCurrentSpan() {
    console.log(this.id)
    document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = "Active element's id is " + this.id;
}

var children = document.getElementById("input").querySelectorAll('span');
children.forEach(function(e){
    document.getElementById(e.id).addEventListener("click", findCurrentSpan)
})
```