# Problems when updating state in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, caret

Please, view my js fiddle where I've illustrated the problem

Here's my js fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/jajabya/fb93f7b0/

My goad is to get an `input` tag where special words (like dates or users' names could be highlighted by wrapping in `span` tags)

There must be a problem with `div`, because when I use input field instead everything works fine.

My problem is that I can't make the caret appear in the right place
Every time when the state updates in `onInput`

```
  onInput(event) {
    this.setState({
        html: event.target.innerText.toUpperCase()  
    });

  }
```

the caret rolls back to the beginning

Comment: Just a quick question, why would you want to do this in div element?

Comment: Why do you use `div` instead of `input` tag?

Comment: because in `input` tag I cannot have other html tags. I want special words to be wrapped in a `span` tag with a `class` attribute.

Comment: But you can wrap `input` tag and other tags in `div`

Comment: I don't understand you quite well. My idea is that if a user writes in this field "I want to go there **today**" the word "**today**" would be highlighted. If you could provide me with an example or at least make a hint how to achieve this I would appreciate this @MikhailKatrin

Comment: I didn't get what exactly you want, now I see

Comment: Check out https://draftjs.org/ if you find difficulty going forward with the `contentEditable` div. Easy and understandable API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My idea is to save the current caret position in the state, and set it back via a ref in [`componentDidUpdate()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) (since ref doesn't rerender the component).

**Note:** This is a prototype idea, that I've never battle tested, so use with caution.

*The caret position code was take from this answers:*

1. [Code for getting the caret position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767848/get-caret-cursor-position-in-contenteditable-area-containing-html-content)
2. [Code for setting caret position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249095/how-to-set-caretcursor-position-in-contenteditable-element-div)

```js
class Editable extends React.Component {
  componentDidUpdate(prev) {
    const { position } = this.props;
  
    if(position !== prev.position && this.ce.childNodes.length) {
      const range = document.createRange();
      const sel = window.getSelection();
      range.setStart(this.ce.childNodes[0], position);
      range.collapse(true);
      sel.removeAllRanges();
      sel.addRange(range);
    }
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div
        contentEditable
        className={this.props.className}
        onInput={this.props.onInput}
        ref={ce => this.ce = ce}
        suppressContentEditableWarning>
        {this.props.html}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    html: 'Text',
    caret: 0
  };

  handleInput = (event) => this.setState({
    html: event.target.innerText.toUpperCase(),
    position: window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).startOffset
  });
  
  render() {
    return (
     <Editable
        {...this.state}
        className="Editable"
        onInput={this.handleInput} />
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  demo
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="demo"></div>
```