# How can I get the element at the current cursor position in contenteditable?

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

I need to prevent users from hitting the enter key if the cursor is in certain positions:

```
        this.contentArea.addEventListener('keypress', e => {
            if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                if (insideForbiddenElement)
                    e.preventDefault();
            }
        });
```

Is there a way to consistently get this? It only needs to work in the latest firefox / chrome.

Comment: It is only supposed to prevent if the cursor is on the `insideForbiddenElement` element?

Comment: it would be inside an anchor element for example, I don't want to add line breaks inside links

Comment: Could you add the element(s) it is supposed to prevent on in your code? That seems like a crucial part.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get caret (cursor) position in contentEditable area containing HTML content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767848/get-caret-cursor-position-in-contenteditable-area-containing-html-content)